# Connection reset by {ssh hostname} port 22

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, connection, reset, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi with the command `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` but I keep getting these messages:

```
ssh -v pi@raspberrypi.local 
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to raspberrypi.local [2601:47:4001:d250:88ff:ddb5:f761:74d2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/liz/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to raspberrypi.local:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 2601:47:4001:d250:88ff:ddb5:f761:74d2 port 22
```

I have a hunch that it has something to do with the fact that I previously ssh-ed into a different raspberry pi with the exact same hostname and username, but I don't know how to fix it so that I can access this one (and probably rename it to avoid this problem in the future).  I tried doing `ssh-keygen -R raspberrypi.local` but I'm still getting the same messages.
Is there more I need to do to remove it?  I'm also using a mac running on Sierra 10.12.6.  I tried looking through similar issues but couldn't find anything that worked.
Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the two devices are also trying to use the same IP address?

Comment: That could be, although the first pi has been offline the entire time I've been trying to connect.  Would I need to reroute it or reconfigure it somehow?

Comment: Never mind then. It would only be an issue if both were on the network with the same IP at the same time

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had this problem too.

Here's the solution that worked for me:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/60375/26923

In essence:

```
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

I believe the problem is that the keypair files that are generated on first boot were corrupt (perhaps from plugging and unplugging power during the setup process).

Comment: Expanding the partition via raspi-config. Then enabling ssh. I knew better. But I wanted to see, since it gave no warning (other than a reset was necessary... might not have read past that).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing `dpkg` via homebrew, and re-flashing the SSD card and then it worked.  Not really sure why it was so finicky but helpful information in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.